# SharePoint redirects me to non-existent Account/Login page

Tags: authentication, web-application, login, windows-authentication, page-not-found

I'm running into a weird situation. I have two web applications, both using Windows Authentication. They are both using the default login page, both disallow anonymous access, no other special configuration.

Both site collections are publishing sites.

When I navigate to Web Application 1 (port 80), after logging in, I see the landing page for the site collection, and everything works as expected.

When I navigate to Web Application 2 (port 81), after logging in, SharePoint tries to redirect me to [MySiteUrl]/Account/Login. There is no such page, or configuration that I am aware where this is specified. Because the page cannot be found, it directs me to the PageNotFoundError screen. Oddly enough, I am authenticated, so clicking "go to the site home" link does take me back to the home page.

[image]

The situation happens when accessing it internally on the server, or externally, so I don't think it's related to Access Mappings.

This is a fresh install of SharePoint, so I'm not really sure what could be the problem.

Comment: It's interesting that you masked the IP address, despite that it's listed in your request URL.

Comment: Can you confirm a few items for me? It's been awhile since I've done this, but can you go to "<enter your site>/_layouts/AreaWelcomePage.aspx"  and see if it gives you the start page (and confirm that it isn't set to the Account/Logon page. If that doesn't work, can you check central administration (if this is a server versus multi-tenant) and go to Manage Web Application, and verify if everything is good on the ribbon under the "Authentication Providers".

Comment: @QuinnJohns looks like my obfuscation skills are lacking. I confirmed that the welcome page for both sites are /pages/default.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up being a very specific issue. Someone had added a reference to WebMatrix.WebData.dll in our SharePoint deployment project. Apparently the mere presence of this assembly caused this issue.

After removing this to the assembly, and making sure no packages referenced it, the problem was fixed.